# How to tell Resharper to replace all occurrences of "default" with "default(T)" during code cleanup?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, code-cleanup

I ran code cleanup on my solution, and it replaced all occurrences of "default(T)" with "default" but my particular solutions get pumped through a Jenkins pipeline that requires C# 7.0 conformity.

Is there a way to configure Code Cleanup in Resharper to do the opposite?  Namely, replace all occurrences of "default" with "default(T)"?

Comment: Is your project set to use C#7.0? If so, I would consider Resharper changing this to be a bug.

Comment: if not then from docs *ReSharper automatically detects C# version based on the associated compiler. However, you can specify the target C# version explicitly — right-click the project in the Solution Explorer ...* and so on

Comment: The reality is, I don't care whether I have to use VS or Resharper to fix the problem - either one would be acceptable.  But setting all my projects across all solutions to C# 7.0 is not an acceptable solution.  I don't believe you can set a VS Solution to a specific version of C# anyway - you have to do this by project.

Comment: @ShaneOborn _my particular solutions get pumped through a Jenkins pipeline that requires C# 7.0 conformity_ - so it seems to me that specifying the language version is essential?

Comment: To be clear, even setting the project to C# 7.0 is only going to help going forward anyway.  I am looking for a Code Cleanup solution where I can configure it to replace all occurrences of "default" with "default(T)".

Comment: `csharp_prefer_simple_default_expression = false:error` to get an error that must be resolved to compile. Also, code cleanup should be able to fix it based on that setting.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? What .NET Framework are you targeting? The `default` literal was introduced in C#7.1. Is it possible to upgrade Jenkins to deal with later C# versions?